# I can’t transfer many objects through the controller(((

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, freemarker

When I try to transfer a lot of data through the controller, I get an error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
>   Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.psu.projectmethod.domain.wrappers.UserSet'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute com.psu.projectmethod.domain.wrappers.UserSet] for value 'com.psu.projectmethod.domain.User@23'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate Collection type: com.psu.projectmethod.domain.wrappers.UserSet
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.psu.projectmethod.domain.wrappers.UserSet'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute com.psu.projectmethod.domain.wrappers.UserSet] for value 'com.psu.projectmethod.domain.User@23'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate Collection type: com.psu.projectmethod.domain.wrappers.UserSet

I did everything according to examples from stackoverflow and based on this article https://www.viralpatel.net/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/. Please help me fix this problem ((

My controller methods:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('_2_TEACHER')")
@GetMapping("/project/{projectId}/party/create")
public String viewTeacherCreateProjectParty(
        @PathVariable("projectId") Project project,
        Party party,
        Model model) {
    Set<User> users = userService.userList(Sort.by("username"));
    UserSet userSet = new UserSet(users);
    model.addAttribute("project", project);
    model.addAttribute("party", party);
    model.addAttribute("users", userSet.getUsers());
    return "teacherProjectPartyCreate";
}

@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('_2_TEACHER')")
@PostMapping("/project/{projectId}/party/create")
public String processCreateProjectParty(
        @PathVariable("projectId") Project project,
        @Valid Party party,
        @ModelAttribute("users") UserSet users,
        Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("project", project);
    model.addAttribute("party", party);
    Long projectId = projectService.createProjectParty(project, party, users);
    return "redirect:/projects/project/" + projectId;
}
```

Freemarker form:

```
<form action="/projects/project/${project.projectId}/party/create" method="post"
                          style="color: #757575;">

                        <!-- CSRF Token -->
                        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}"/>

                        <div class="md-form">
                            <input type="text" id="partyName" name="partyName" value="${party.partyName!''}"
                                   class="form-control ${(partyNameError??)?string('is-invalid', '')}" required>
                            <label for="partyName">Group name</label>
                            <#if partyNameError??>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    ${partyNameError}
                                </div>
                            </#if>
                        </div>

                        <select name="users" class="selectpicker"
                                data-header="Select users"
                                data-live-search="true"
                                data-selected-text-format="count"
                                data-size="auto"
                                data-style="btn-unique"
                                data-width="auto"
                                multiple
                                title="Select users"
                        >
                            <#list users as user>
                                <option value="${user}">${user.fullname}</option>
                            </#list>
                        </select>

                        <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">

                            <button type="button" onClick='location.href="/projects/project/${project.projectId}"'
                                    class="btn btn-outline-info waves-effect">
                                Отмена
                            </button>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect">
                                Save
                            </button>

                        </div>

                    </form>
```

My Entity Creation Method

```
public Long createProjectParty(Project project, Party party, Set<User> users) {
    project.addParty(party);
    party.addUsers(party, users);
    projectRepo.save(project);
    return project.getProjectId();
}
```

Helper methods to add bi-directional associations:

```
public void addParty(Party party) {
    party.setPartyProject(this);
    this.projectParties.add(party);
}

public void addUsers(Party party, Set<User> users) {
    party.setPartyUsers(users);
    this.partyUsers.addAll(users);
}
```

ManyToMany association mapping:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE}
)
@JoinTable(name = "party_users",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "fk_party_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_id")})
private Set<User> partyUsers = new HashSet<>();

public class UserSet implements Set<User> {
private Set<User> users;

public UserSet(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}

public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
... // getters, setters and Set metods
```

Comment: I would break down this issue by starting with sending 1 or 2 objects to the views, then slowly by slowly, add the next until you isolate the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

After analysing your logs I've found that it's something bad with your request.

Read this log entry carefully:

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.psu.projectmethod.domain.wrappers.UserSet'
```

It seems you're trying to send `String` in the place where it's expected `UserSet`. If this behavior is desired please consider to use Converters. Check the [article](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters)